# Where to find a list of hard low melting point alloys?

Tags: metallurgy, alloys

Im looking for alloys that have a melting point lower than 600°C and as high as possible hardness. Is there a search engine I could use to find those alloys with their physical properties?

Comment: Solder may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MatWeb for a preliminary search of materials with desired physical properties.

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I needed